# How to hot encode a dataframe column with multiple strings?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on building a regressor model to predict the food delivery time.

This is the dataframe with a few observation

[image: 1]

If you observe the Cuisines column has many strings.  Used the code

```
pd.get_dummies(data.Cuisines.str.split(',',expand=True),prefix='c')
```

This helped me split the strings and hot encode, however, there is a new issue to be dealt with.

Merged the dataframe and dummies. fastfood appears in 1st and 3rd rows. Expected output was a single fastfood column with value 1 on first and third rows, however, there are two fastfood columns are created. fastfood(4th column) is created for first row and fastfood(15th column) for thrid row.

[image: 2]

Can someone help me solve this help me get a single fastfood column with value 1 on first and third rows and similarly for the other cuisines too.

Comment: It still is the same. This code again creates two different fastfood columns.

Answer (score 1):

The two `Fast Food` are different by a trailing space. You probably want to try:

```
data.Cuisines.str.get_dummies(',\s*')
```